# Swift: Subclassing ViewController and with add target?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

I am creating an app with swift and I subclassed a view controller in which I add a tap gesture recognizer and an NSNotification that listens for the keyboard appearing. I put the selector for the keyboardWillShow in a function in my base view controller. When I subclassed my view controller, however, and I had the keyboard show, my app terminated with an NSException that said that it could not find the selector. Can anyone explain why this happened and how I can fix it?

Here is the functionality in my base view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setNotificationListers()
    setTapGestureRecognizer()
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func setNotificationListers() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func setTapGestureRecognizer() {
    let tapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "closeKeyboard")
    tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)
}

func closeKeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func keyboardWillShow() {
    self.view.frame.origin.y += CGFloat(keyboardHeight)
}

func keyboardWillHide() {
    self.view.frame.origin.y -= CGFloat(keyboardHeight)
}
```

I did not override anything in my subclass. What will be inherited and what will not?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector declaration require a parameter, but your function does not require a parameter.

Either remove `:` from your selector declaration

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

or change your function

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y += CGFloat(keyboardHeight)
}
```

and do the same for `keyboardWillHide`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `Selector` method have a `:`, that means your method need have a parameter.
So, you should change two your methods to this:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y += CGFloat(keyboardHeight)
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.view.frame.origin.y -= CGFloat(keyboardHeight)
}
```

Anyway, xCode 7.3 has change the way to implement `selector`. And you can use this great lib https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager to handle the keyboard pushing up. Very simple to use.